# Publish to specific channel/Group

Tags: python, django, websocket, swampdragon, sockjs-tornado

I am looking into the `swampdragon` [chat_example](https://github.com/jonashagstedt/swampdragon/tree/master/chat_example/chat_example). In the `router.py` as per documentation `get_subscription_channel` gives channel name.
When I tried to change the retrun value it still works.

How can I limit the messages to specific group/channel. What things I need to do in the front end.

```
from swampdragon import route_handler
from swampdragon.route_handler import BaseRouter


class ChatRouter(BaseRouter):
    route_name = 'chat-route'
    valid_verbs = ['chat', 'subscribe']

    def get_subscription_channels(self, **kwargs):
        return ['chatrm']

    def chat(self, *args, **kwargs):

        errors = {}

        if errors:
            self.send_error(errors)
        else:
            self.send({'status': 'ok'})
            self.publish(self.get_subscription_channels(), kwargs)


route_handler.register(ChatRouter)
```

Here is the subscription method.

```
function subscribe () {
    swampdragon.subscribe('chat-route', 'local-channel', null, function (context, data) {
        // any thing that happens after successfully subscribing
    }, function (context, data) {
        // any thing that happens if subscribing failed
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also came across the same issue. Here the problem is that **you are not publishing data to the channel that you have subscribed** . You subscribed for channel named **'local-channel'** but in your router.py you are publishing or routing data another channel named **'chatrm**'. Thats why you are not getting any notification. There are two ways you can fix it.

**1.** You need to change the get_subscription_channels method in **router.py** as shown below.

```
def get_subscription_channels(self, **kwargs):
    return ['local-channel']
```

OR

**2.** Change the **subscription** method like the one below:

```
function subscribe () {
swampdragon.subscribe('chat-route', 'chatrm', null, function (context, data) {
    // any thing that happens after successfully subscribing
}, function (context, data) {
    // any thing that happens if subscribing failed
});
}
```